# Which context do i use to load resources in a singleton?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, android-context, soundpool

I have a SoundPool that I want to play in different fragments. So I load it within a singleton. What context do I have to use?

```
object PingSoundPool {

fun loadpings(note: Int) {

    val context = Application()

    val mAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .build()

    val mSoundPool = SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(9)
        .setAudioAttributes(mAttributes)
        .build()

    val cping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.cping, 1)
    val dbping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.dbping, 1)
    [...]

    if (note == 0) {}
    if(note == 1)
        mSoundPool.play(cping, 1f, 1f, 1, -1, 1f)
    if(note == 2)
    mSoundPool.play(dbping, 1f, 1f, 1, -1, 1f)
    [...]
    }
}
```

If I use it like this, loading it in my activity´s onCreate like this `PingSoundPool.loadPings(0)` and accessing it in an onClickListener with `PingSoundPool.loadPings(1)` should work, no? 
At runtime, I get a NullPointerExeption like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.soulfetch2/com.example.soulfetch2.FullscreenActivity}:
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' 
on a null object reference
```

The exeption points out the line `val cping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.cping, 1)`
The R.raw. file exists, but isn´t accessible somehow. I think I may be using the wrong context. Or I implement the right context in the wrong way.
Anyway, help is greatly apreciated.

---

EDIT:

The original question was solved but there is still something wrong: The code as it is reloads the SoundPool every time it tries to play a sound. Hay anyone got a good idea how to load it seperately, so that the calls of `PingSoundPool(this).loadPings(Int)` just play the sounds and not reload everything?

Another thing: When I do `PingSoundPool(this).loadPings(Int)` from an Activity, all works well. From a fragment however, I get a TypeMismatch "Required: Context, Found: MainFragment". I can work around it with `PingSoundPool(this.requireContext()).loadPings(2)` or `PingSoundPool(this.context!!).loadPings(2)` but that seems not like the best thing to do. Any suggestions?

Here´s the class I use instead of the object now:

```
class PingSoundPool(context: Context) {

    val mAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
        .build()

    val mSoundPool = SoundPool.Builder()
        .setMaxStreams(9)
        .setAudioAttributes(mAttributes)
        .build()

    val cping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.cping, 1)
    val dbping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.dbping, 1)

fun loadPings(note: Int) {

    if(note == 1)
        mSoundPool.play(cping, 1f, 1f, 1, -1, 1f)
    if(note == 2)
    mSoundPool.play(dbping, 1f, 1f, 1, -1, 1f)
[...]
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call it from your activity's onCreate, why don't you pass also `Context` as a parameter?

The function will be like this:

```
fun loadPings(context: Context, note: Int) {

    //val context = Application()   //Remove this line

    val cping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.cping, 1)    //Here it's used the parameter context
    val dbping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.dbping, 1)
    [...]
}
```

And in your Activity's onCreate you call it in this way:

```
PingSoundPool.loadPings (this, 0)
```

**EDIT:**

If you create a PingSoundPool object, it won't reload every time the files: so you can do this in your activity:

```
class YourActivity ... {

    companion object {   //So it is accesible from other classes with YourActivity.pingSoundPool
        lateinit var pingSoundPool: PingSoundPool;
    }

    @Override
    ... onCreate(...) {
        pingSoundPool = PingSoundPool(this)
        ...
    }
}
```

Then if you need to play sound (I consuel to change the function name) you can do it with

```
pingSoundPool.load(1)                 // Inside of YourActivity
YourActivity.pingSoundPool.load(1)    // Outside of YourActivity
```

In this way I solved also your last question, but maybe you want to know how to pass the right `Context` object from a `Fragment`: in your `Fragment` you can declare a `Context` object (or a `YourActivity` object, it's a child of `Context`) and assign it a value from the `onAttach(..)` method, in this way:

```
class YourFragment ... {

    private lateinit var mContext : Context
    private lateinit var mActivity : YourActivity   // You don't need both

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        mContext = context!!

        if (context is YourActivity)
            mActivity = context
    }
}
```

Then inside your Fragment you can call `PingSoundPool(mContext)` (or `PingSoundPool(mActivity)`).

Note that `onAttach` is called before any other callback method, so also before `onCreateView`.

You can also get the Fragment context with `getContext()` (just `context!!` in Kotlin), but I think the above solution is better and safer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you take a look at the follow-up question as well? I´ve added it to the original post.

Comment: Done, check it.

Comment: I tried to implement your code, but I get `sample 7 not READY` when I try to play the sound from my Fragment. Any idea why?

Comment: What's that? A Log Message? A compiler error? A Log Error? On which line? Could you be more clear?

Comment: It was from Logcat at runtime, when trying to play a sound. Anyway, I had one line wrong in the fragment. now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't create an instance of `Application` as a new `Context`, you need to pass an existing `Context` to your method:

```
fun loadpings(note: Int, ctx: Context) {
    ...
    val cping = mSoundPool.load(ctx, R.raw.cping, 1)
}
```

If you call that method from Activity just pass `this@YourActivity`:

```
PingSoundPool.loadpings(0, this@YourActivity)
```

or just

```
PingSoundPool.loadpings(0, this)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this line:

`val context = Application()`

Here you're creating a new `Application` object which you shouldn't do. You have two options here:

1. Make `PingSoundPool` a `class` instead with a `Context` as a constructor parameter, and use that instead:

```
class PingSoundPool(private val context: Context) {
  ...

  fun loadpings(note: Int) {
    [...]
    val cping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.cping, 1)
    val dbping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.dbping, 1)
    [...]
  }
```

2. Make this method `loadPings` accept `Context` as argument:

```
fun loadPings(note: Int, context: Context) {
   [...]
   val cping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.cping, 1)
   val dbping = mSoundPool.load(context, R.raw.dbping, 1)
   [...]
}
```

Then for both methods 1. and 2. pass the `Application`/`Activity`/`Fragment` you're using as the `Context`. Personally, I prefer method 1. since that scales better, should you add more methods relying on `Context` in the future.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you take a look at the follow-up question as well? I´ve added it to the original post.